# LINQ GroupBy on single property

Tags: linq, group-by

I am just not understanding the LINQ non-query syntax for GroupBy.

I have a collection of objects that I want to group by a single property. In this case *Name*

```
{ Id="1", Name="Bob", Age="23" }
{ Id="2", Name="Sally", Age="41" }
{ Id="3", Name="Bob", Age="73" }
{ Id="4", Name="Bob", Age="34" }
```

I would like to end up with a collection of all the unique names

```
{ Name="Bob" }
{ Name="Sally" }
```

Based on some examples I looked at I thought this would be the way to do it

```
var uniqueNameCollection = Persons.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

But I ended up with a collection with one item. So I though maybe I was over complicating things with the projection. I tried this

```
var uniqueNameCollection = Persons.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Same result. I ended up with a single item in the collection. What am I doing wrong here? I am just looking to `GroupBy` the *Name* property.

Comment: Have you tried `Persons.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().ToList()`?

Comment: The code you have in your question should work. Can you please show the valid C# source **you used** for populating your `Persons` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = Persons.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct().ToList()
```

If you just want names

Comment: I had not tried that. Thank you. Any idea why my `GroupBy` was not working?

Comment: No, it seems like it should work fine. Are you sure that there a 2 separate names in the list?

Comment: I am sure that I am stupid. I went back to look at the object list and the values for `Name` were `null`. No wonder they were all grouping together. They were all null. Thank you for the answer though. `Distinct()` does seem like an easier way.

Comment: No probs, we all have those moments

Answer (score 2):

LINQ's `GroupBy` doesn't work the same way that SQL's `GROUP BY` does.

`GroupBy` takes a sequence and a function to find the field to group by as parameters, and return a sequence of `IGrouping`s that each have a `Key` that is the field value that was grouped by and sequence of elements in that group.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) 
{ ... }
```

So if you start with a list like this:

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name;  
}

var people = new List<Person> {
    new Person { Name = "Adam" },
    new Person { Name = "Eve" }
}
```

Grouping by name will look like this

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<Person>> groups = people.GroupBy(person => person.Name);
```

You could then select the key from each group like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = groups.Select(group => group.Key);
```

`names` will be distinct because if there were multiple people with the same name, they would have been in the same group and there would only be one group with that name.

For what you need, it would probably be more efficient to just select the names and then use `Distinct`

```
var names = people.Select(p => p.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Maybe Friday is not my day, but I tried to see the difference between your GroupBy/Select and the questioners one. Looked again, again... Am I studid (not a genius nor stable)? I don't see the difference. Still +1 because you explained the GroupBy as was asked for

Comment: Yes, it is a little puzzling that it would return a single item with the data presented. Maybe we need more source code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uniqueNameCollection = Persons.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

Appears valid to me.  .net Fiddle showing proper expected outcome: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2hqOvt

Answer (score 0):

Using your data I ran the following code statement

```
var uniqueNameCollection = people.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

The return results were  List

- Bob
- Sally

With 2 items in the List
run the following statement and  your count should be 2.

```
people.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.Key).ToList().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, download a nugget MoreLinq
    using MoreLinq

```
var distinctitems = list.DistinctBy( u => u.Name);
```